# Escaping special characters (ø, æ) for use inside a url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I try to display an image with a URL source in an iOS application, but it doesn't show up.

The url of the image is live example path.

When escaping this string using the following Objective-C code:

```
 NSString *url= [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)originalpath, NULL, CFSTR("øæ"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

the result is (with encoding of øæ) : live xml path

All my files where the URLs are stored use text encoding (UTF-8).

How do I escape the URL in a right way, such that the image will be displayed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

don't go for ascii encoding try it

```
NSString *URLString = [yourImagepath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
```

I hope it will help you out.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Zohaib. Excellent solution. it worked pretty well.

Comment: I am sorry that stack overflow doesn't allow multiple one ups, this answer really deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to escape your url-string, before using it as an url...

```
NSString *URLString = [yourImagepath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
```

Comment: Downvote: This is exactly what the author the post already did - and is visible in the text of the question too...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on iOS with German umlauts. The `NSURL` category [NSURL+IFUnicodeURL](http://files.iconfactory.net/sean/NSURL+IFUnicodeURL/) solved the problem for me, don't get scared by the amount of C code in there, it's well-hidden :)

Comment: bro am i supposed to add the two files NSURL+IFUnicodeURL (.h and .m) in my project. The downloaded files contain too many files within. Kindly guide me through :)

Comment: Just drop everything in your project, including the `IDNSDK` folder. This contains the actual Unicode conversion libs, the category uses them internally.