# Danish special characters (æ, ø, å) are not getting encoded properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I'm facing the url encoding issue for `kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1` encoding:
I have tried as below:

```
NSString *urlEncoded = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                         NULL,
                         (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                         NULL,
                         (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,?%#[]% ",
                         kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1);//æøå (if kCFStringEncodingUTF8 >> not encoding properly)
```

It's returning NULL value.

i'm writing an image to path which has the danish special chars.  the issue is the file name must not encoded and it should be display with same chars with-out any encoded chars.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe, this answer can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8166560/1090309

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko sorry, i'm writing an image to path which has the danish special chars.  the issue is the file name must not encoded and it should be display with same chars with-out any encoded chars.

Comment: I didn't get, why you can't use that code